# Using Username and email as login in wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I followed the document
http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/10/07/email-username-with-identity-server/ to allow users login with their Email ID.But it is is mentioned if we enable

```
<EnableEmailUserName>true</EnableEmailUserName>
```

then users cannot login with their username or any attribute other than email.

Our use case as LDAP as a secondary user store and we also do in time provisioning.So we will need to allow users to login with either email or username. Is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: Did you do the required changes in user-mgt.xml file ? What is exact error you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow [this guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Authentication+using+Attributes) to achieve this. Following are the steps you need follow.

## Step 1

Configure the LDAP user store related configurations using the
    user-mgt.xml file found in the /repository/conf directory.

Configure UserNameSearchFilter that helps to search for the user object in the LDAP using both mail and uid attributes.

```
<Property
name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=person)(|(mail=?)(uid=?)))</Property>
```

Disable UserDNPattern property, if it is currently enabled.

```
<!--Property
name="UserDNPattern">uid={0},ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org</Property-->
```

The mail attribute has requirements that are unique. If you are
    using the mail attribute, you need to open the carbon.xml file found
    in the /repository/conf directory and uncomment the
    following. See here for more information on email authentication.

```
<EnableEmailUserName>true</EnableEmailUserName>
```

## Step 2

If you want to work with multiple attributes (basically to retrieve internal roles with multiple attributes), you must add following property in the /repository/conf/user-mgt.xml file. This can be done only once you have installed the WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 along with the Service Pack.

```
 <Property name="MultipleAttributeEnable">true</Property>
```

## Step 3

To test this, restart
    the Identity Server and try to log in to the management console by
    providing both the mail and uid with the same password.

Comment: Thanks.We tried the above steps but we face issue when we are using it in multitenant domain.

Comment: When we have user in tenant=mycompany.com with

 
         uid =user1 and email =user1@yahoo.com


if i login using the email it is working fine.But when i login with uid it fails and in the searchQuery log we get the below 
     DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user with SearchFilter: (&(objectClass=person)(|(mail=user1@mycompany.com)(uid=user1@mycompany.com))) in SearchBase:  Is there any other configuration needs to be done ??

Answer (score 0):

Multi-attribute login is not supported for the versions before 5.10.0. The above suggested approach too could cause some inconsistencies during some flows.(Refer [here](https://medium.com/identity-beyond-borders/how-to-enable-multiple-mutable-login-identifiers-in-wso2-identity-server-4240fefa3508) for the reason).

Solution to adopt multi-attribute login for earlier Identity Server versions is described in this [blog post](https://medium.com/@sajithekanayaka/solved-multiple-login-identifiers-for-wso2-identity-server-78005599d97e)

But from 5.10.0, WSO2 supports this by introducing new set of user store managers as explained [here](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/setup/configuring-the-primary-user-store/).